# Orientation of a UIWebView HTML5 video

Tags: iphone, video, html, uitabbarcontroller, orientation

I am using a `UIWebView` in a Tab Bar application and I am having a `<video>` tag for some m4v clips. I have the desired behavior so far, however when the device goes from portrait to landscape, the video (and the controllers) remain as before. 
I am not 100% sure, but I suspect that the `UITabBarController` is "locking" the orientation change (as the same page in mobile Safari does autorotate). Can that be the case? If yes, is there a workaround? It is important to show all other content (of this and the other tabs) in portrait but the video in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

`UITabBarController` doesn't autorotate by default, you need to subclass it and override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`.

Comment: So you think that this is what actually causes the problem, right? Can you explain a bit better what to do after subclassing UITabBarController?

Comment: That's strange, this works (with or without subclassing UITabBarController) as desired in 3.1.3, but not in iOS4. I also tried to change webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback but with no luck.. Can you think of something in iOS4 that prevents the video from autorotating in landscape?